# Yii Framework ERROR 404 -Could not resolve the requisition "pdfs/andre.pdf"

Tags: php, pdf, yii, hyperlink, yii-chtml

**Greetings,
I have a folder with many pdf files. What i want is to be able to generate links in a view, and when i click one of those links the browser render's the file. In last case, at least the browser downloads the file to the hard-drive. Neither of both could implement.**

For now i have this code in my index.php file. It sets the pdfs folder and list the files in my browser window because of the foreach loop.

```
<?php
$cfileDir = Yii::app()->file->set('pdfs/');
$ficheiros = $cfileDir->getContents();
if (isset($ficheiros[0])) {
foreach ($ficheiros as $index => $ficheiro) {
    $nomeFicheiro = substr($ficheiro, strrpos($ficheiro, '/') + 1);
    echo CHtml::link($nomeFicheiro, array('pdfs/'.$nomeFicheiro)) . "<br/>";


   }
} else {
    echo "Não existem ficheiros disponíveis para download.";
}
?>
```

This code shows the links generated for each file inside the folder PDFS, but when i click on a link it display ERROR 404 could not resolve the requisition "pdfs/nameoffile.pdf".
I don't have any code im my Controller, is it needeed ? I use the extension Cfile and its methods to manage files, but i don't think it as influence on the ERROR 404.

**

### What to do... Any solutions ? Thanks in advance.

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
echo CHtml::link($nomeFicheiro, Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/pdfs/'.$nomeFicheiro) . "<br/>";
```

As `array('pdfs/'.$nomeFicheiro)` is the link to `pdfs` controller and `$nomeFicherio` action which it seems you don't have it.

On the other hand, it is suggested not to break `MVC` structure and separation of concerns.

Comment: SOLVED.
Your suggestion solved the issue, and now everything works the way i wanted to. Also, many thanks for the valuable explanation about how things work.
Thank you very much.